# Primefaces tabs not loading dynamically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a 3 layer tab structure in primefaces.First layer contains 2 tabs say Business and Individual.Business tab contains some other tabs.Now the issue is if I click on Individual tab then all the tabs inside Business tab also gets loaded even though there is no dependency between them.
PS : I'm using Primefaces 5.3
Here's my code:

```
<p:tabView id="i" widgetVar="TabV" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
        <p:tab title="Business">
            <p:tabView id="Busi" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="C&amp;I">
                    <p:tabView id="CI" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                        <p:tab title="Business1">
                            <ui:include src="CI//xyz.xhtml" /> 
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:tabView>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="CRE">
                    <p:tabView id="CRE" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                        <p:tab title="Business2">
                            <ui:include src="CRE//def.xhtml" />
                        </p:tab>
                    </p:tabView>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Individual">
            <p:tabView id="PFS" prependId="false" cache="false" dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="Individual">
                    <ui:include src="PFS//abc.xhtml" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```